# How can I specify Quality Of Service in ESB 4.9.0?

Tags: qos, wso2-esb

I'm trying the new 4.9.0 ESB version, having some experience in using 4.8.1 version.

I used to specify my own security policy using the Quality Of Service area in custom proxy configuration, but in the latest version that area is empty - without options.
I cannot post images yet, see the linked image:
https://goo.gl/photos/Dq65EWbf1BwdsxLC7

Do I have to activate it in some configuration file?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ESB 4.9.0 management console not support anymore for this functionality. Even though this feature isn't provided by the ESB management console itself same functionality can be achieved by the new WSO2 Dev Studio 3.8.0.

WSO2 always motivate to use dev studio to prepare required artifacts to the ESB rather than the web console.

You can follow this link to understand, [How to enable proxy service security in ESB 4.9.0?](http://prabu-lk.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-to-enable-proxy-service-security-in.html)